# Exposing entire Freemarker data model to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, freemarker

I'm wondering is there an easy way to expose the entire data model of a Freemarker template to JavaScript, preferably converting it to a JS object literal somewhere along the way.

I know how to iterate through the keys:

```
  <#list .data_model?keys as key>
  </#list>
```

And presumably I could build a global JS variable within the template as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could traverse the whole data model with FreeMarker and then produce the "source code" for a corresponding JSON object, but you'd have to deal with things like string escaping (e.g. with the [js_string builtin](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_js_string)) and potentially large (recursive) object graphs.

Some years ago I wrote a generic data model "dumper" which prints a nice tree representation of the FreeMarker data model. It's probably not exactly what you want or need, but maybe it's an inspiration. You can find it [here](http://chaquotay.net/freemarker/dump.ftl).

Comment: I ended up going another way entirely for the solution but this is helpful thanks!

Comment: I made a JSON macro out of Chaquotay's dump. https://github.com/MajorLeagueBaseball/freemarker-json

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use Jackson or any other json api to convert the object to json and then add the json string to the model.

Example using spring MVC:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test() throws Exception {


    String output = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(new HashMap<String, Object>());

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    model.put("result", output);
    return new ModelAndView("page", "model", model);
}
```

In freemarker

${model.result}